# Virtuemart 2 - How i can add item into cart session with virtuemart_product_id?

Tags: php, function, joomla, virtuemart, cart

My Sample Code to try,  automatic add to cart with Product ID.
I know i need the quanitity too, but i dont know exactly the code.
With this code it doesnt work.

```
$array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']);   //read the cart session
$products = $array->products;                        //list the products 

if (array_key_exists('53', $products)) {             //if productID 53 then
  $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
  $quantityPost= 1;                                  //set quantity on 1
  $virtuemart_product_id = 1;                        //set product id on 1
  $cart->add(array(1));                              //add into cart product with id 1
  //$tmpProduct = $this->getProduct((int) $virtuemart_product_id,$quantityPost); //?
  echo "Article added!"; }                           //echo Message
else { 
  echo "Nothing added!"; }                           //echo Message
```

Comment: Your title is way too long.  Try shortening it to something both meaningful and readable.

Answer (score 2):

The exact way of adding item to the Cart is like follows its an ajax call function .

```
var data = "quantity[]="+qty+"&virtuemart_product_id[]="+pid
    //data      =   encodeURIComponent(data);
    jQuery.ajax({               

                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
         });
```

If you want to do it from php section go to the cart controller file and check function addJS then pass the corresponding param to that function.

Hope this may help you..

Comment: http://docs.virtuemart.net/api-vm2/de/d52/controllers_2cart_8php_source.html

Line 65 up to 91 is a functiona add (before addJS)
Is it possible to use that ,too ?

But i dont know how to uses this code.
I only define the virtuemart_product_id which should automatic add into the cart session.

Comment: Ok, You can use that function for your purpose. before calling $cart->add() just assign $_POST['virtuemart_product_id'] = $virtuemart_product_id; then try it.let me know its worked or not

Comment: Hi,
The code seems to be ignored. I tried these things

$_POST['virtuemart_product_id'] = $virtuemart_product_id;
$cart->add(array(52)) ;
$cart->add() ;
echo " article was added";

the Echo message comes but no new Product in the Cart. 

Eventually you have still an Idea

Comment: If you pass product id as argument it will not work ,bocz on definition it tooks like getvar so its should be  $_POST['virtuemart_product_id'][] = $virtuemart_product_id; Try this too.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the VirtueMart API for correct cart handling. http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=125870.msg431290#msg431290

In short, VirtueMart uses by default a call done with jQuery.getJSON which is a shorthand for an Ajax function. So all this above is not necessary. In doubt it is also unsecure. You should use the VM API to retrieve and store the cart object.